# Understanding Drainage Density?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, watershed, density

I have calculated drainage density for two watershed and need to make sense of the numbers. One watershed has a drainage density of 1.08 km/km2 (area=32 sq. km and total stream length=34.436 km). The second watershed has a drainage density of 1.23 km/km2 (area=20 sq. km and total stream length=24.586743 km).

Could someone explain if these numbers are high/low?

And what they mean in the real world?

I’ve been Googling these questions and have had no luck. Below is a map I have created showing areas of high density - this, along with calculating watershed DD, is the purpose of my study.

[image: Drainage Density]

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after much research - these numbers are too low. I plan on calculating stream length using L = 1.4 Ad^0.6, where L is the channel length in miles and Ad the drainage area in square miles (Fluvial Processes in Geomorphology by Luna B. Leopold, M. Gordon Wolman, John P. Miller). After this, I will use the length to recalculate drainage density.